# How not to get duplicate data while loading the data into hive using spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Lets suppose we are going to load the data in hive using spark with a CSV file (date contains 24 (10 records) ,25(25 records) and 26(100 records)).

Already in hive we have the partition data for date 24(20 records) and 25 (10 records).

In spark if we use OVERWRITE keyword based on the partition dates then all the data will be deleted for 24 and 25 and and new records will be inserted. So now we will be having the data count for date 24 -> 20 records and for date 25 -> 20 records.

If we won't use OVERWRITE keyword then hive will get duplicate (old+new) records, eg; date 24-> 30 records, date 25-> 35 records.

what approach we can follow so that only 26 data should go to hive.

Note: Since every day the transactions are happening in GB's, so we will not inspect the file everyday.

Comment: Why csv instead of parquet?

Comment: Is there the option for you to partition by date in hive?

Comment: Any format yo can select no issues with fie format. I have just given a random one.

Comment: yes we have the partitions based on the dates (24,25,26)